# dojo TabContainer via zend render no thing

Tags: dojo, zend-form, tabcontainer

I have mess all day with this decorator, i read many source to implement dojo tab container via zend framework, but i tried it self result nothing.
is there any misscode with this snippet

```
$form = new Zend_Dojo_Form();
$form->setName('name')
    ->setLegend('legend')
    ;
$form->setDecorators(array(
            'formElements',
            array('tabContainer', array(
                'id'          => 'tabContainer',
                'style'       => 'width: 600px; height: 500px;',
                'dijitParams' => array(
                'tabPosition' => 'top'
                    ),
                )),
                'DijitForm',
));

$a = new Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_TimeTextBox('time');
$a->setLabel('label');

$sf = new Zend_Dojo_Form_SubForm();
$sf->setDecorators(array(
    'FormElements',
    array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'dl')),
    'ContentPane',
    ));
$sf->addElement($a);
$form->addSubForm($sf, 'subform');
```

thanks before

Answer (score 0):

[this?](http://zendgeek.blogspot.com/2009/07/create-dojo-tab-cotainer-in-zend.html)

[or this?](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dojo.view.html#zend.dojo.view.dijit.layout)

Dojo view helpers in Zend use captureStart() and captureEnd()